# Derivative of $\Im(z(x))$ with respect to $x$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, complex-numbers

Suppose $z(x)$ is a complex variable depending on a real one $x$. Then, if I write $z(x)=z_1(x)+iz_2(x)$ I can compute the following derivative: $$\frac{d\Im(z(x))}{dx}=\frac{dz_2(x)}{dx}.$$ However, WolframAlpha gives the result
$$\frac{d\Im(z(x))}{dx}=z'(x)\Im'(z(x)), $$ which I'm not even sure how to interpret. Is this one of those cases where I should just ignore what it says, or am I making a mistake in my way of taking the derivative?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha interprets $\Im$ as a function and applies the chain rule.

Comment: @Gary Of course this is the chain rule, but it does actually understand that $\Im$ is the imaginary part. I guess it is generally untrustworthy when dealing with complex variables...

Comment: If you interpret $\Im$ as the function of $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ $\Im : (x,y) \mapsto y$ then what Wolfram gave has a sense since $\Im$ is then real-differentiable.